# Can I omit "the" in those sentences?

Tags: usage, definite-article

Sometimes I'm not sure whether I should use "the" in a sentence.

### Descriptive noun + name

In math:

- Option 1: Point A is equidistant from lines l and l'.
- Option 2: The point A is equidistant from lines B and C.

In another context:

- Option 1: I find drawing A nicer than drawing B.
- Option 2: I find the drawing A nicer than the drawing B.

In my opinion, option 1 is always better. Am I wrong? Are there similar constructs where "the" should be used?

### Product

Let's say there is a company called Samtec building a text editor.

- Option 1: Samtec text editor is faster than competing products.
- Option 2: the Samtec text editor is faster than competing products.

Which one is the best?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the definite article "the" when you are referring to something *specific* that would not otherwise be recognised as such. For example, you might say "*the* car" when referring to a specific car, because there are many cars; but if you had already identified a specific car by some other means there would be no need for the definite article. You *wouldn't* say "*the John's car*"; you would just say "John's car", presuming that your audience knows who John is.

In your first two examples, you refer to *specific* drawings by labelling them "Drawing A" and "Drawing B". As this naming convention already makes it clear which is which, there is *no need* for the definite article.

The correct renditions are:

> Point A is equidistant from lines B and C.

and

> I find drawing A nicer than drawing B.

In your final example, it depends on whether you are using the three-word phrase "Samtec Text Editor" as the complete name for a product. If that is a recognised name, then you are naming a specific product and there is no need for the definite article:

> Samtec Text Editor™ is faster than competing products.

*However*, if that is *not* the name of the product and you are simply *calling it* "a text editor" to show that it is one of many text editors, then the definite article may be required to differentiate it from the other text editors you refer to:

> The Samtec text editor is faster than the other text editors.

An alternative way of phrasing this without the definite article might be to use the possessive:

> *Samtec's* text editor is faster than the others.

This identifies it as being the text editor belonging to Samtec, whatever the actual name of the product is.